# How can I confirm that there is a WiFi network card in my desktop or not?

Tags: wifi-driver, wireless-networking

Is there any way that I can determine that there is some wi-fi card present in my CPU ?
I think there is some wi-fi card, but I don't know what is it. And I haven't installed any driver for that. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: When you say CPU, do you mean you have a desktop computer? The CPU is the little chip inside of the computer that runs the computer. It is about 1.5 x 1.5 inches for recent processors. What you are talking about is simply called the "computer". Another way to determine if you need to look any further is if there is an antenna on the back, like in these pictures (you will only see the antenna, as the rest will be internal): http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=pci+wireless+adapter&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1385&bih=895&wrapid=tlif131090754170610&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi

Answer (score 2):

You can see all hardware in control panel > device manager or my computer > right click > properties > system...

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Approches you can try:

use Device Manager(on Windows) to see the list of Networking adapters installed. Look also for anything marked unknown.

Look behind the case. Most desktop Wifi Cards have antennas.

Open the case. Look for a PCI slot Wifi Card or read the name of the motherboard and look up the specs on the internet.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. In the Network Adapters I find only Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller. Does it mean anything to wi-fi ?

Comment: @Shanky That is your LAN adapter. Did you build the PC yourself or bought a pre-assembled pc.